# Draw Rectangle on transparent form is very slow

Tags: delphi

AlphaBlend and DoubleBuffered set to True. I have Duo Core 2Ghz and drawing takes 100% CPU, even i had once BSOD. My goal is selecting custom area on screen and get coordinates. Enabling/disablin Windows Aero doesnt speed up. Thanks for help.

[image]

```
unit ZaznaczenieObszaru;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  private
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  rysuj: boolean;
  poczatekX, poczatekY, xGlobalne, yGlobalne: Integer;
  kolorIzy: TColor;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
  Width := Screen.Width;
  Height := Screen.Height;
  rysuj := False;
  kolorIzy := 14413224;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = #13) then Close;
end;

procedure TForm3.Image1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap := nil;
  Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := kolorIzy;
  poczatekX := X;
  poczatekY := Y;
  rysuj := true;
end;

procedure TForm3.Image1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if rysuj = true then
  begin
    xGlobalne := X;
    yGlobalne := Y;
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap := nil;
    Image1.Canvas.Brush.Color := kolorIzy;
    Image1.Canvas.Rectangle(poczatekX, poczatekY, xGlobalne, yGlobalne)
  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.Image1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  rysuj := False;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I would take a desktop screenshot when the selecting starts and work with that *frozen* desktop screenshot rendered on a non alpha form.

Comment: Why are you re-drawing it on every little pixel the mouse moves? No wonder it's slow, because it keeps redrawing rapidly. You're supposed to put all drawing in the `OnPaint` event.

Comment: This code is simply wrong in many ways, first and foremost because it repeatedly clears the `Image1.Picture.Bitmap` and because it's drawing directly onto the `Image1.Canvas`, which is improper. TImage is a container for an image, not a drawing surface. If you want to draw, create a bitmap and draw to that bitmap's canvas, and then assign the completed bitmap to the image control.

Comment: @Jerry: No, drawing to a bitmap doesn't need to be in the OnPaint event. That's only for drawing directly on the form. (But the code is terribly wrong for other reasons.)

Comment: @KenWhite Oh, I didn't notice that, I was assuming it was drawing to the form, which is how it should have been.

Comment: @Ken White now i draw on bitmap and assign to the image control on timer. I know it isnt perfect, but for me is ok. Now ~50% CPU

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a `TPaintBox` instead of `TImage` (It's Canvas is not meant for such usage as @Ken already commented) and draw your rectangle on the `TPaintBox.OnPaint` event. don't draw on Mouse events, but rather use `TPaintBox.Invalidate`. Here is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  poczatekX := X;
  poczatekY := Y;
  rysuj := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if rysuj then
  begin
    xGlobalne := X;
    yGlobalne := Y;
    PaintBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  rysuj := False;
  PaintBox1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if rysuj then
  begin
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := kolorIzy;
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Rectangle(poczatekX, poczatekY, xGlobalne, yGlobalne);
  end;
end;
```

I guess the same could be applied using only the `TForm` itself without any graphic controls, by drawing to the Form's canvas directly (same events as with the `TPaintBox`).

Comment: "guess the same could be applied using only the TForm". I did it now and also removed Invalidate; from MouseUp to see selection. From BSOD to this code :)

Comment: to further improve your coding please use class field members (of the Form) with meaningful names instead of global variables. you could also replace `poczatekX, poczatekY` to a `poczatek: TPoint` (I would name it `StartPoint` for example). where `StartPoint := Point(X, Y)`. and read as `StartPoint.X; StartPoint.Y` same goes for `Globalne` (`EndPoint`).

Comment: @kobik He does use meaningfull names, but they are in Polish language. In polish "poczatek" means "beggining". And since you are suggesting the replacing of specific X and Y variables with TPoints why not simply suggest creating of one TRectangle variable, and then in OnMouse down changing the Left and Top parameters, and on MouseMove changing the Width and height parameters of this TRectangle instead.

Comment: @SilverWarior, You mean a `TRect` maybe, which is also a good option. programming code should be IMHO be international. and English is the mostly common for code naming. since I'm not polish I can't tell that "poczatek" is a "beginning" - I can only learn that from the context. Delphi also have some conventions which one  might want to adopt... just saying.

Comment: @kobik could you also suggest something to have always painted rect on mouse up? 95% is ok, but sometimes on fast mouse up there is no rect.

Comment: and sorry for Polish, next time i will paste only english, but still im gonna use Polish in my code. I just preffer it and programming is just my hobby, i dont wanna be profesional programmer.

Comment: to always paint rect on mouse up: simply add another variable `rysuj2`. on `FormMouseDown` set it to False.  on `FormMouseUp` set it to True (with `Invalidate`). on `FormPaint` check for `if rysuj or rysuj2 then`...

Answer (score 1):

Try my [NLDXPSelection](http://www.nldelphi.com/showthread.php?19564-Hoe-XP-selectiekader-te-maken) component which is a non-visual component that provides drawing blue alpha blended selections on any control, form or screen. It has properties `OnResize` and `OnFinish` that tell the selection coördinates.

Source can be found [here](http://svn.nldelphi.com/nldelphi/opensource/ngln/NLDXPSelection/) (open source).